# Why StatefulSessionComponent cause a memory leak?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, java-ee-7, heap-dump, wildfly-9

Because of a `Java Heap Space` error I did a heap dump of my `Java EE 7` program running on a `WildFly 9` server. Then I used `Eclipse Memory Analyser` to analyse the dump. `Eclipse Memory Analyser` reveals the 2 following problems which are the same:

> One instance of "org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateful.StatefulSessionComponent" loaded by "org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader @ 0xe0130378" occupies 168 975 304 (36,60%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]" loaded by "".
>
> One instance of "org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateful.StatefulSessionComponent" loaded by "org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader @ 0xe0130378" occupies 155 775 312 (33,74%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]" loaded by "".

I have few Stateful EJBs on my program. Does that mean those EJBs are never garbage collected ? Any idea how to solve this problem ?

**EDIT**

Here a capture of the dominator tree:
[image: Dominator tree]
It seems that the class `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node` is the cause.

Comment: what does the concurrentHashMap hold deos it hold some session objects?

Comment: The `ConcurrentHashMap$Node` holds 3 entries. One of them is `org.jboss.ejb.client.UnknownSessionID`. There are also a `org.jboss.as.ejb3.cache.simple.SimpleCache$Entry` and another `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node`.

Comment: I think you have to set the timeout of ejb sessions properly  check this link https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowDoTheTimeoutsWorkWithEJB3StatefulBeans?_sscc=t